# Is buffering a TextReader needed?

Tags: c#, .net, io

Is there a point to buffering a `TextReader`?

`TextReader` has its own internal buffer and I can set the size on creation, so is there a reason I would want to use my own buffer and call `Read( buffer, index, count )` over just getting char by char using `Read()`?

Comment: multibyte characters are quite trendy nowdays

Comment: If you are really reading characters, then it might be faster to iterate over an array.

Comment: Does it need to be faster? Perhaps "more readable" might be preferable until performance is an issue?

Comment: I need to read and process every character of the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who knows how complicated the internals of the Read() method are?  Hopefully, they are optimized to be as fast and as efficient as possible.  But chances are it is faster to call a single Read(...) method and then iterate over the array of characters.  But another important question is: does it matter in your case what the performance difference is?  If you are just reading 100 chars once or twice a minute, then the performance probably doesn't matter.  If you are processing multi-megabyte files sequentially, then you probably want the best possible performance.  If the latter is the case, then the same answer always applies: measure, don't guess.

Comment: Using the buffered read seems to be the faster way to do it. Even when iterating all the chars in the buffer after the read, it is still faster.

Comment: This is an important lesson that a lot of developers never ever get: just because there is more code in the solution doesn't mean it is slower. Many developers think that if they write less code, that automatically means the solution is faster. There is no free lunch.  You have to think about how much code is involved in the methods you are calling. The methods are there to make devs' lives easier.  But that often means that the methods are designed to do more than the dev is trying to do. The result: if the dev writes the code specifically for the solution, it is somtimes faster.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're doing. If your reading fixed length records that aren't delimited by a CR+LF pair from a stream, you'll want to do something along the lines of

```
public static void Process()
{
  using ( Stream s = OpenCommunicationsStream() )
  using ( TextReader tr = new StreamReader(s)   )
  {
    char[] record = char[80] ;
    int chars_read ;

    while ( (chars_read=tr.Read(record,0,record.Length)) == record.Length )
    {
      DoSomethingWithRecord( record ) ;
    }
    if ( chars_read > 0 ) throw new InvalidDataException("wrong length record") ;
  }
  return ;
}
```

Why you might use `Read/0` rather than `Read/3` or `ReadBlock/3` is entirely dependent upon your needs and your context. For instance, if you're writing a parser, you might want to process the inbound stream of text on a character by character basis, especially since `TextReader` gives you one character of lookahead via its `Peek()` method for free.